# How To Parse URL in Deno

Tags: deno, urlparse

How do you parse a URL in [deno](https://deno.land/)  like `node.js` `url.parse()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No external module is needed to parse URLs in Deno. The [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class is available as a global, just like in your browser:

```js
const urlString = "https://www.google.com";
const url = new URL(urlString);
console.log(`URL: ${url.protocol}//${url.host}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. My JS activity dates way back to well before Firefox 1.0 and sometimes my brain does not quickly absorb all the new stuff that shows up in ECMA Script over time =)

Comment: @TimothyC.Quinn No problem. (Also note that [the same has been true in Node.js since version 10](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#url).)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using the ECMA script's native [URL class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), as illustrated by [jsejcksn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71599970/286807), you can also use [url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) library from the [/std/node](https://deno.land/std@0.130.0/node) compatibility module as follows:

```js
import * as UrlLib from "https://deno.land/std/node/url.ts";
const url = "https://www.google.com"
const purl = UrlLib.parse(url)
console.log(`URL: ${purl.protocol}//${purl.host}`)
```

Output:

```
URL: https://google.com
```